# Customizing (style) ModelMultipleChoiceField in a on ManyToManyFields in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Am trying to customize my checkbox inputs to look like this [[what i want to archive]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p9Rg.png)

so i tried this...

## profile.html

```
<ul class="wt-accountinfo">
{% for key, value in form.interests.field.choices %}
   <li>
    <div class="wt-on-off pull-right">
       <input type="checkbox" id="{{ value }}" value="{{ key }}" name="interests">
         <label for="{{ value }}"><i></i></label>
    </div>
     <span>{{ value | title }}</span>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

which renders the html fine but highlight the select fields from the database

but using `{{ form.interest }}` highlights the selected checked boxes from the database

here is the forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    interests = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=JobsCategories.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['interests']
```

and here is the models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Categories, related_name='interests', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'
```

in the views.py

```
def dashboard_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        account_form = AccountForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid() and account_form.is_valid():
            f_interests = form.save(commit=False)
            for i in request.POST.getlist('interest'):
                f_interests.interest.update(i)
            f_interests.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            account_form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        account_form = AccountForm(instance=request.user)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'account_form': account_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard_profile.html', context)
```

NOTE!!! if i select the options i want and click save, it saves the options i checked to the database

[this is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GTtP.png)

this is it in the admins section

[admin section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ojx.png)

[admin section 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs8Ea.png)

and also when i use `{{ form.interests }}` in the the template it renders fine and highlights the checked option from the database but its not styled

[[how it looks like when i use {{ form.interests }}]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVAQL.png)

i know am missing somtehing in the `profile.html` so please help me out Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing logic within your input tag to apply the existing value of the field choice.

```
<ul class="wt-accountinfo">
    {% for key, value in form.interests.field.choices %}
       <li>
        <div class="wt-on-off pull-right">
           <input type="checkbox" 
            id="{{ value }}" 
            value="{{ key }}"
            name="interests" 
            {% if value %}checked{% endif %}>
           <label for="{{ value }}"><i></i></label>
        </div>
         <span>{{ value | title }}</span>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did as you said it did check but all the options are checked how do I go about it